# How to implement a negative edge triggered D Flip Flop (Master Slave Configuration)?

Tags: flipflop, trigger, edge

Can you please post a picture of the implementation of such flip-flop at logic gate level? How can I easily change a positive edge triggered D Flip Flop to a negative edge? Also, how will the truth table differ from the positive edge?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm almost inclined to answer, but _please_ do look at it again and give it a second's thought. You may have (should have) heard of a thing called an invertor. :)  Also, this sounds a little too homeworky IMO for the liking of the peoples that tend to stick around here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Master%E2%80%93slave_edge-triggered_D_flip-flop

Answer (score 0):

here is link to datasheet for 74LS112
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-wJ3vpt7ZAhVW9mMKHQDuCbwQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fpdf%2Fsdas199&usg=AOvVaw1bLUvWMKMq_A9rtgMzL0Bf

and here is logic-diagram

[image]

You should download a PDF of the TTL databook, and read it. 
Or buy a used copy, and flip through it.